# How can I play a sound file "OnTouch"

Tags: ios, audio

I need to play a file when I touch the screen.

I have tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
-(IBAction)play;
{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();

    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;

    soundFileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, 
    (CFStringRef) @"sound1", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);

    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you add a touch handler on your window or main view?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [yourObject play];
}
```